# Как включить в неоф. api Я.Музыки yandex_music shuffle_enabled?

Tags: python, яндекс-музыка

Не могу разобраться как работать с библиотекой "yandex_music", а именно не могу включить режим рандомных треков в яндекс музыке. В документации это UserSettings.shuffle_enabled, но как им пользовать не могу понять.
Вот код:

```
from yandex_music import Client, UserSettings
import config

client = Client(f'{config.TOKEN}').init()
UserSettings = UserSettings.Client(f'{config.TOKEN}').init()

while True:
    if int(input("Введите значение:\n1 - Вкл.\n0 - Выкл.")) == 1:
        print('\n\nВкл!')
        UserSettings.shuffle_enabled(1)
    else:
        print('\n\nВыкл!')
        #UserSettings.shuffle_enabled()
```